# Multiple ranges for QDoubleSpinBoxes in QT

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am building an application that makes use of multiple frequency ranges. I need the user to be able to increase/decrease the values in the `QDoubleSpinBox`, as well as type in the value. If I increase the value to a number out of one range, I would like the value to jump to the next range (same principle for decreasing a value).

Does a `QDoubleSpinBox` provide this kind of behavior? I can't seem to find an answer for what I'm looking for. I've tried setting a range using `QDoubleValidator`, but I don't think it supports multiple ranges (unless I'm missing something). I've also tried using range checks with if statements with the `valueChanged()` signal that gets emitted, but there must be a simpler way, right?

Here's an example of how I'd like the doubleSpinBox to behave:

**Starting Value**: 9.75

**Range 1**: 9.75 - 9.95

**Range 2**: 10.15 - 10.40

**Range 3**: 17.2 - 20.4

If value goes above 9.95, jump to 10.15.

If value goes above 10.40, jump to 17.2, etc.

I would also like to have the same behavior when decreasing the value (jumping back down to **Range 1** if value drops below 10.15).

I would like to do this without writing multiple `if/else if` statements if I can avoid it.

Comment: You can always keep an eye on what the current value is and jump to the next range if appropriate. The spinbox has nothing to do with that, it's just showing the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to create multiple ranges is not a good solution. You should consider your problem in a different way: you have a single range from 9.75 to 20.40 with forbidden values.

So, if you override method such as `QDoubleSpinBox::stepsBy()` and `QDoubleSpinBox::valueFromText()`, you will be able to discard the values outside your ranges:

```
class Spinbox: public QDoubleSpinBox
{
public:
    Spinbox(): QDoubleSpinBox()
    {
        setRange(9.75, 20.4);
        setSingleStep(0.1);
    }

    virtual void stepBy(int steps) override
    {
        double const newValue = checkValue(value() + (steps * singleStep()));
        setValue(newValue);
    }

    virtual double valueFromText(QString const& text) const override
    {
        qDebug() << text;
        double const newValue = QDoubleSpinBox::valueFromText(text);
        return checkValue(newValue);
    }

    double checkValue(double newValue) const
    {
        qDebug() << newValue << value();
        if (9.95 < newValue && newValue < 10.15)
        {
                if (newValue > value())
                    return 10.15;
                else
                    return 9.95;
        }
        else if (10.4 < newValue && newValue < 17.2)
        {
            if (newValue > value())
                return 17.2;
            else
                return 10.4;
        }
        return newValue;
    }
};
```

Comment: I didn't even think about it that way, that makes things much more simple!